# I can't find maven from "Build Tool" in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, build-tools

As I describe in the title, the maven item should be find in **Settings** --> **Build Tools**, however there is no this item in my IDE, I'm using **IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.2.2**. [image]

Comment: Have you installed the plugin??

Comment: @SupunWijerathne Thanks for your remind, it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, I just need to check the **Maven Integration** plugin and apply it as following.
[image]